# Sieve script not working on TLDs

Tags: sieve

I have the following Sieve script, which is supposed to discard or reject any emails from domains like **xxx@xxx**, **.xyz** or ...**.top**. However it is not discarding them?

```
require ["reject"];

if address :matches :domain "from" ["*chencoin.com", "*.guru", "*.icu", "*.casa", "*.monster", "*.cyou", "*.top", "*.fun", "*.xyz"] {
    #reject "Not allowed.";
    discard;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know if this is the full Sieve script. I suspect it's not and that other `fileinto` (or `keep`) actions follow that save the mail into a different folder.

All `discard` does is [canceling the implicit keep](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5228.html#section-4.4), so *if* other `fileinto` actions follow, they will happen.

This should work if it's the full script:

```
if address :matches :domain "from" ["*chencoin.com", "*.guru", "*.icu", "*.casa", "*.monster", "*.cyou", "*.top", "*.fun", "*.xyz"] {
    discard;
}
# end of script
# (implicit keep happens if no discard was issued.)
```

This will *not* discard as you would expect:

```
if address :matches :domain "from" ["*chencoin.com", "*.guru", "*.icu", "*.casa", "*.monster", "*.cyou", "*.top", "*.fun", "*.xyz"] {
    discard;
}

fileinto "INBOX";
# end of script
```

I'd recommend using an explicit `discard; stop;` to prevent this:

```
if address :matches :domain "from" ["*chencoin.com", "*.guru", "*.icu", "*.casa", "*.monster", "*.cyou", "*.top", "*.fun", "*.xyz"] {
    discard; stop;  # <- Note the extra "stop;" here
}

# ... more rules and actions ...

# end of script
```

The alternative is to have everything in one `if/elsif/elsif/...` logic so the mail never hits any other rules that would lead to a `fileinto`.

(In my opinion this behavior is one of the things that make Sieve a little frustrating.)